# Doing multilanguage routes with MapRoute

Tags: asp.net

I want users can access to my website with

```
English version: web.com/news/bla-bla
Spanish version: web.com/noticias/bla-asdf
...
```

And I think that modify RouteConfig.cs is the solution, but I don't know how do it exactly. I accept solutions that don't be MapRoute.

My 1st failed test:

```
namespace MyWebsite
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: {id},
                defaults:
                    // In a web running in a server I should use local resources
                    if ({id} == ("about" || "sobre" || "sur"))
                    {
                        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "about"}
                    }
        }
    }
}
```

My 2nd failed test:
ERROR: (Additional information: A route named 'About' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique.) --> I can't "relink" a route.

```
        string[] about = { "about", "sobre", "sur" };
        for (int i = 0; i < about.Length; i++)
        {
            //if ({id}.Equals(about[i])
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "About",
                url: about[i],
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "About"}
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to map each route individually by passing a dynamic language value to the controller. For example:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "News English",
            url: "News",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "News", language = "en-US"}
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "News Italian",
            url: "Notizie",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "News", language = "it-IT" }
        );
```

and in your controller you can get the language and do what you want with it (for example set the current culture and current UI culture):

```
    public ActionResult News(string language)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(language);
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(language);

        //Do what you want

        return View();
    }
```